# Автоматически уменьшить padding между элементами при уменьшении родительского контейнера? Не срабатывает box-sizing: border-box

Tags: html, css, разметка

Помогите пожалуйста. Хотелось бы чтобы между `link1`, `link2`, ... уменьшалось расстояние при уменьшении ширины окна (а именно чтобы уменьшался `padding` вплоть до 0), но чтобы при максимальной ширине окна между ними оставался заданный `padding` (в моем случае `padding: 0 25px`). `box-sizing: border-box` не работает. Пробовал много разных вариантов, но ничего не выходит: `link`-и выходят за рамки родительского окна сразу же при уменьшении родительского окна, а хотелось бы держать их внутри до последнего.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 25px;

    border: 1px solid red;
}
.wrapper ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    list-style: none;

    border: 1px solid green;
}

.wrapper ul li {
    padding: 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<nav>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li style="margin-left: auto"><a href="#">link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну смотри, 1vw = 1% вот и укажи padding:3vw; примерно ...

Comment: Используйте `vw` или `%`, хотя не могу понять зачем `padding` доводить до `0`, при этом придумывать вычисления для автоматизации. Что вам мешает использовать `media` запросы, а если еще и известно сколько будет занимать меню по ширине просто уберити у первого элемента `margin-left: auto` и не будет никаких проблем.

Comment: согласно макету по которому я верстаю - сначала уменьшается margin левого элемента, затем до планшетной ширины уменьшается расстояние между всеми элементами. Но похоже я ничего не упустил.. думаю нужно применять медиа выражения и высчитать паддинг в vw вплоть до планшетной ширины. Спасибо за ответы. Жаль нету более технологичного свойства которое может удержать элементы внутри контейнера. Казалось бы с этим должен был справиться box-sizing

Comment: Мы не экстрасенсы, добавьте всю информаци в вопрос, в том числе и скрины желаемого результата

Comment: добавил изображение в вопрос

Comment: Я кажется понял... box-sizing: border-box не влияет на padding и border, а ТОЛЬКО на ширину контента. Так как контент всегда впритык, то элементы начинают уходить за страницу и предотвратить это можно только пересчитыванием padding, тоесть указывать его в относительных величинах начиная с какой-то ширины используя media. Еще раз спасибо всем за ответы

Answer (score 1):

Уберите просто ваш инлайновый `style="margin-left: auto"`

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 25px;

    border: 1px solid red;
}
.wrapper ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    list-style: none;

    border: 1px solid green;
}

.wrapper ul li {
    padding: 0 25px;

    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: если просто убрать style="margin-left: auto", то не решается проблема о которой я говорю.

Comment: добавил изображение и новый коммент под вопросом.